# Blender 2.8 select a part of an edge loop

Tags: modeling

In Blender 2.79 I was able to select a part of an edge loop selecting one edge and then with CTRL and click on another edge. With this method Blender was selecting the edges in between.

I was not able to find out if this has changed in 2.8 (i know this is still beta).

Comment: It still works.

Comment: I think you should try Shift + Click to select edges Ctrl just makes the selection faster.

Comment: @WhatAMesh  Thank you guy's. I realized that an add-on is creating this behavior!